# Can someone explain me the code given below?

Tags: php, arrays

`$array_words` is an array which has every 'single' word from a file in it.

---

```
$array_2_words = implode(" ", $array_words);

$array_2_words = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9-\' ]/i", "", $array_2_words);

$array_2_words = str_replace("  ","",$array_2_words);

$jk = explode(" ",$array_2_words);

$i = sizeof($jk);
$j = 0;

$array_2_words="";

for($j=0;$j<$i-1;$j++)
{
    $array_2_words[] = $jk[$j]." ".$jk[$j+1];
}
```

I know what the result of this code is, making an array with 2 words each. 
For example: It will make from a sentence like this: `This is a test sentence` the following array:

`This is
 is a
 a test
 test sentence`

But would someone be so kind to comment (each|some) line(s) to how it exactly does this from an array with 1 word in every entry to 2 words like my example.

I could just leave this code in my script but I will only fool myself by not knowing how it works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Step over the code with a debugger? You will see the results of each statement right away.

Comment: issue a `var_dump` on every "obscure" line, in order to know what's happening ^^

Comment: You can pretty much ignore everything but the last `for` loop, that's where all the "magic" lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic happens only on the last line.

```
$array_2_words[] = $jk[$j]." ".$jk[$j+1];
```

This line means: Take an array of words ($jk) and combine word n and word n+1 from the array of words and push them into $array_2_words.

so what happens is:

```
$jk[0]." ".$jk[1] = "This" + " " + "is" = "This is"
$jk[1]." ".$jk[2] = "is" + " " + "a" = "is a"
$jk[2]." ".$jk[3] = "a" + " " + "test" = "a test"
```

Comment: It actually looks really simple like this! Thanks for your simple explanation. so meaning if i change: `for($j=0;$j<$i-2;$j++)` and `$array_2_words[] = $jk[$j]." ".$jk[$j+1]." ".$jk[$j+2];` i can create an array that captures 3 words in each entry right?